# laravel api without respond

Tags: laravel, api

I have a issue, after i eliminate cors policy on laravel i sending some json data to check respond. But nothing happens...

I sending request by axios using react.js, i sending json data collected from state.

and now i trying to collect that data by laravel, but that is hardest patch.

already try something like that:

```
$content='test';
return Response::$content;
```

or just echo 'test' but nothing comes...

My code is inside controller.

```
class testRequest extends Controller
{
public function show(Request $request)
{

    //$data = $request->json()->all();
    // $experience = $data->experience;

    $content='test';
    return Response::$content;
}
}
```

for now i expect to get respond like 'test' but after that i will need to send a link to file path for respond.

Answer (score 1):

the Response::$content is just wrong... the :: operator is used to access static member functions or attributes of the Response class... you should do something like this:

```
return Response::json(['test' => $content]);
```

or

```
return response()->json(['test' => $content]);
```

in order to respond with a JSON document.

Comment: Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/creator
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: respond working only when i type ulr in browser but when i sending axios request. i got nothing

Comment: You should set the header `Accept` to `application/json` on your **CLIENT** to let the server know that you accept json responses.

Comment: i got it header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type : application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
in bootstrap/app.php

Comment: the header on axios not on the server

Comment: as like on my example above Content-Type: application/json this is header send by axios.

Comment: not `Content-Type` but `Accept`. You need both to be set to `application/json`

Comment: both is set. i think the issue maight be becouse i run laravel on local host.